# How to import the Tailwind directives only in one Next.js page?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

Need to use tailwind in a next.js project, but only in one page

How to import the Tailwind directives
`@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`,
without affecting all other pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same steps as mentioned [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs).

However in `Step 3` , just give the path of your only file where you want Tailwindcss.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/<path_of_your_file>",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: This works for limit the local purge of the classes, but not for the directives that i mentioned that go in the css file